# PSR-2 Coding standard for arrays and method chaining?

Tags: php

What's the PSR-2 Standard coding convention for initialization of arrays and method chaining?

```
$foo = array(
    'one' => 1,
    'two' => 2
);

$rows = DB::select('mytable')
    ->where_id($id)
    ->get_one();
```

Comment: What is `PSR-2 Standard coding convention`?

Comment: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md

Comment: @Jocelyn "PHP Standards Recommendation" drafted by the Framework Interoperability Group, fun fun

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PSR-2 currently doesn't specify either

Comment: does any of the other ones do?

Comment: "Doesn't specify neither" is a double negative, but you can't make one letter edits.

I'm not sure how those two specifications are "confusing". It's pretty straightforward.

If you're declaring an "abstract" or "final" method, you have to format it like this:
`abstract protected function myMethod();`
`final public function myMethod();`

Static methods should be like this:
`public static function myStaticMethod();`

This allows readers to quickly see what's what, and allows for easier code completion in IDEs.

Answer (score 4):

At this stage neither of those are explicitly covered in the PSR-2 standard. In the [conclusion](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#7-conclusion) it does note that a number of areas are intentionally omitted, including:

> - Operators and assignment
> - Inter-line alignment

The only relevant guidelines would be the more general ones regarding things like line lengths and number of spaces for indenting.

Other standards that do deal with those subjects include [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php) and [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.html).