# Standard In PHP for Return Lines when Chaining Function Calls

Tags: php, coding-style

I haven't been able to find an answer for this in any of my Google searches but is there a standard/best practice for return lines before or after the arrow operator when I chain function calls across lines?

The two options I've come up with are return after the arrow operator:

```
$myclass->
    foo->
    bar->
    baz();
```

And before the arrow operator:

```
$myclass
    ->foo
    ->bar
    ->baz();
```

We're trying to stick to PSR-2 coding standards if at all possible.

Comment: I'd always go for the second option, arrow before just seems so much more readable

Comment: Which ever you like the best.  Personally, I like the second one, but that's my opinion.

Comment: Both works but I have almost only seen the second version.

Comment: I prefer the first option, same with commas for function args or multiple elements within an array. But it's personal preference.

Answer (score 4):

PSR2 doesn't specify. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11894206/2016155. Second option is more readable though if you ask me.